# Solidity function returns empty array on ethersjs/hardhat but not in remix ide?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

Hi I am learning Solidity and I have the problem that a function seems to work on remix ide but not with etherjs/hardhat? (The abi's are the same too)

The code:

```
function getOwnCards() external view returns(uint[] memory _cards) {
    uint[] memory result = new uint[](userToCardsCount[msg.sender]);
    uint counter = 0;
    for (uint i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        if (cardIdToUser[i] == msg.sender) {
            result[counter] = cards[i];
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The result in remix ide:

```
    0:
uint256[]: _cards 62180033277912311002789072835418559502128313467724667052439679862541172075622,31220469133090072532919887703804680190688655804240516732101690706958488894069,35568354368614544905898949308353469583138320508979990175291873927902398948450
```

The result in ethersjs:

```
[]
```

The FE code:

```
const getCards = async () => {
    if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined'){
        //@ts-ignore 
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum) 
        const contract = new ethers.Contract(cardsAddress, Cards.abi, provider)
        try {
            const data = await contract.getOwnCards()
            console.log(data)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also log the `contract` to see if you successfully build the contract

Comment: https://github.com/AlwinBrauns/ETHCardNFT/blob/main/contracts/Cards.sol

Comment: did you ever call the `generateCards` in front end to push data to `cards`

Comment: Yes I did generated cards it also seemed to work . I will check with hardhats console next time I'm working on it

Comment: I fixed it by not using msg.sender but a given address, dont know why it doesnt work with msg.sender

Comment: I actually know why now. Its because I gave the provider address to the function call and not the signer, so msg.sender was not the sender

Comment: Hey, if the problem has been solved you can post the solution as an answer and mark it as accepted instead of editing the question, it helps filter out solved questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 1:

change msg.sender to a given parameter:

```
function getCardsByOwner(address user) external view returns(uint[] memory _cards) {
    uint[] memory result = new uint[](userToCardsCount[user]);
    uint counter = 0;
    for (uint i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        if (cardIdToUser[i] == user) {
            result[counter] = cards[i];
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

### Solution 2:

call function in FE Correct

```
const getCards = async () => {
    if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined'){
        //@ts-ignore 
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum) 
        const signer = provider.getSigner()
        const contract = new ethers.Contract(cardsAddress, Cards.abi, signer)
        try {
            const data = await contract.getCardsByOwner(signer.getAddress())
            console.log(await contract.getOwnCards())
            console.log(data)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add context to answers please.